# AWS Express Step Function execution within Express Step Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-serverless, aws-step-functions

In the `Standard Workflow` we can happily invoke another `Standard workflow` using

```
{
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::states:startExecution.sync:2",
  "Parameters": {
    "StateMachineArn": "${NestedStateMachineArn}",
    ...
  }
  ...
```

When we try to do the same with `Express workflow` we of course get the `Express state machine does not support '.sync' service integration`. That is stated by `aws` so expected behaviour.

Is there another way to execute `Express workflow` from another `Express workflow` and somehow get the execution result/output? I can think of a last resort - use `Lambda` function to execute the nested workflow sync and wait for a response, that said, it will increase the cost having a function waiting for `StateMachine` needlessly.

I tried to look around but couldn't find this documented anywhere.

Comment: Please change your selected answer from the one saying this is not possible to the one that explains how this is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute another workflow, you just can't wait for the results. I believe you just need to remove `.sync` from the resource. If you are needing to wait for the results of the second function you won't be able to do that within an express workflow.

From [Service Integrations with AWS Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-service-integrations.html)

> Standard Workflows and Express Workflows support the same set of service integrations but do not support the same integration patterns. Express Workflows do not support Run a Job (.sync) or Wait for Callback (.waitForTaskToken). For more information, see [Standard vs. Express Workflows](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-standard-vs-express.html).

Comment: I should have clarified in my question, I am looking to get output from the nested Step Function. I have edited and added that in.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a way to do that, outside of what you described. I was trying to think of another way, but I don't think so. The API Gateway integration with step functions has the same limitation for express workflows, so while you can make a call to an API Gateway as a request/response from the first step function, the second would only be able to run an express workflow without getting the results. If the second step function could be a standard workflow then you'd have some options.

Answer (score 5):

You can execute Express executions synchronously using the [`StartSyncExecution`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_StartSyncExecution.html) API, which is now supported as an [AWS SDK integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/supported-services-awssdk.html) in Step Functions using `"Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:sfn:startSyncExecution"`.

```json
"NestedExpressWorkflow": {
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:sfn:startSyncExecution",
  "Parameters": {
    "StateMachineArn": <your_express_state_machine>,
    "Input.$": "$"
  },
  "Next": "NextState"
}
```